# 783: Unexpected token at ' ' (JSON: :ParseError)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

i recently downloaded vagrant version 2.2.19 and oracle virtual box version 6.0.24 on windows 10
when i vagrant up i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/bin/vagrant:194:in `<main>'
        8: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/bin/vagrant:194:in `new'
        7: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in `initialize'
        6: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:984:in `process_configured_plugins'
        5: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:957:in `find_configured_plugins'
        4: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:957:in `each'
        3: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:959:in `block in find_configured_plugins'
        2: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.19/gems/vagrant-2.2.19/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:187:in `machine_config'
        1: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 783: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)
```

what can i do to fix it

Comment: Did you find a solution? Mine started to do that today and I didn't updated or anything

Comment: not yet...i'm yet to find it

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried removing the local `.vagrant` directory inside your project directory?
- Have you tried `vagrant up --provision`?

Comment: not yet, 'i'll try it and let you know